# How can I select different row using condition and then select different column based on that same condition in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have following table(X).

```
pId     | threshold     |  upperLimit    | lowerLimit
-----------------------------------------------------
1       |   15          |  10            |  5
2       |   10          |   9            |  4
```

I have variable `v_count, v_score, v_pId, v_pId2`.

Currently, we have following query.

```
select case when v_count >= threshold
            then lowerLimit
            else upperLimit end into v_score
from X
where pId = v_pId
```

Now I want to result based on requirements which is
When `v_pId2` is not null then if `v_count` is less then threshold, then where clause for upper query is  `where pId = v_pId` but if `v_count` is greater then threshold, then where clause for upper query is  `where pId = v_pId2`.

Example,

```
   Input(possible values of variable)  |   Output
---------------------------------------|-----------
  v_pId    |    v_pId2    |   v_count  | v_score
-----------|--------------|------------|-----------
    1      |      2       |    16      |   4
    1      |      2       |    14      |   10
    1      |    null      |    16      |   5
    1      |    null      |    14      |   10
```

How can I achieve this?

My approach is(not work for all)

```
1st run this query:-

select pId into v_pId
from X
where pId = case when v_pId2 is not null and v_count >= threshold 
                 then v_pId2 
                 else v_pId
group by pId;

Then run this query:-

select case when v_count >= threshold
            then lowerLimit
            else upperLimit end into v_score
from X
where pId = v_pId
```

Is there any other way?(using single query)(modifying table is not an option)

Comment: Your question will be easier to answer with some sample and expected data!

Comment: edit:- what can be input and based on that input what I expect as an output. @cdaiga is that okay or want some more data.

Comment: When you say input, then where is that input come from ?

Comment: Input means possible value of variables, it's come as a parameter of SP

Comment: If possible then create and add SQL fiddle

Comment: _"not work for all"_ Why not? How does it fail?

Comment: for `v_pId=1,v_pId2=2,v_count=14` in this case it fails. @underscore_d